# Filter pandas dataframe by row with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm sure there might be a simple solution but I'm quite new to Python. 
I have a `Pandas DataFrame` with strings and NaN values. In this Dataframe I want to search for special parts of strings. This should be done row by row and the found strings will be written in a list with the same number of rows as the Dataframe (means if the partial string I was looking for could not be matched in the row the entry in the list should be 'none').

I tried: `result.loc[result[0].str.contains("hello", na=False)]`
but this only gives me back the rows where first column contains the word hello...

I was thinking about a for loop searching with regular expressions in every row:

```
row = df.iloc[0:100]
for item in row:
    row_dict={}
    hello = re.search(r"hello.*", item)
    if hello is None:
       hello = "NaN"
```

Maybe there is also a simpler way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the test purpose, I defined the source DataFrame as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    ['Halo Mike', 'How are you?', np.nan],
    ['Hello John', 'Good morning', 'What a nice day'],
    ['Ello Jack', 'Xyz hello abc', np.nan]])
```

As you can see, there are 2 elements containing *hello* and
2 *NaN* elements.
Column names are not essential here, so I didn't define them.

The first step is to convert this DataFrame into a *Series*,
with *NaN* values filtered out:

```
ser = pd.Series(data=df.values.flatten()).dropna()
```

`df.values` gets the underlying *Numpy* array, `flatten` reshapes it
to a 1-D array and `dropna` deletes *NaN* values.

Then, to get elements of this Series with `hello` inside (case insensitive),
run:

```
ser[ser.str.contains('hello', case=False)].tolist()
```

In case of our test data, the result is:

```
['Hello John', 'Xyz hello abc']
```

I think, it just what you described in your comment.

For real input data (longer than my example), if you want to limit
the search to just 100 initial rows, change `df.values` to
`df.head(100).values`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I didn't want to have boolean values... I just wanted to return the whole cell of the dataframe that contains the searched string(?).